# Моргание модели при анимации

Tags: delphi, opengl

Добрый день, я еще зеленый в Opengl и возможно всего не понимаю, но у меня происходит моргание модели при ее анимации с включенной двойной буферизацией. Ниже предоставлю ссылку на код, т.к сюда весь не влезет. У меня здесь нарисован танчик и его развороты, но пока они не до конца работают, а также танчик стреляет и в этом идет сама проблема, описанная выше. Помогите, пожалуйста.
**http://qtxt.ru/tanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`procedure TfrmGL.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);` если у вас это привязано к событию `onPaint`, то это неверно...

Рисовать нужно именно по таймеру (в вашем случае).

```
procedure TfrmGL.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
y:=y+z;
refresh;        <---- неверно
FormPaint(self);<---- верно 
end;
```

Ну и соответственно убрать данное событие из `onPaint`

Comment: Спасибо теперь уже не моргает) Пытался 3 дня решить проблему, но безуспешно, а тут всего-то 1 строчка виновата оказалась))

Comment: принимайте ответ если правильно)) и не стоит так разбрасыватся очками.. от них много чего зависит(оО где то эту фразу я уже видел)